# Reflexive pronoun and future tense

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-réfléchis

- *la reine se fera que veut*
- *la reine fera que se veut*
- *la reine fera se que veut*

Which is correct and where or why should I put a reflexive pronoun here?
Is it similar to Spanish?
Does this sentence need reflexive pronoun or not? Can I just conjugate *faire* as *fera* ?

Answer (score 1):

A/ *Vouloir* et *faire* sont des verbes qui peuvent être utilisés de façon pronominale réfléchie.
=> *elle **se veut*** / *elle **se fait*** sont donc des tournures parfaitement légitimes avec donc un *se* pronom réfléchi, et ce, quel que soit le temps de la conjugaison.

Ces verbes n'en restent pas moins transitifs directs => Il faut à ces tournures un complément d'objet direct qui, dans les deux premiers exemples, ne peut grammaticalement être représenté par **que** isolément.
=> Les deux premières tournures sont fautives.

Dans la troisième (*fera **se** que veut*) il n'est pas question d'usage pronominal réfléchi puisque le pronom ne précède pas un verbe. Une telle phrase est fautive.
Elle peut toutefois s'entendre ainsi mais simplement par confusion du pronom réfléchi avec le pronom démonstratif **ce**. => *La reine fera **ce** que veut*

B/ En fait ces tournures sentent le vieux françois du fait de l'ellipse du pronom sujet. *que veut* pour *qu'**elle** veut*.
En l'absence du tag *histoire*, je m'imagine que ce n'est pas le contexte dans lequel tu souhaites un développement. Mais si tu changes d'avis... je développerai dans ce cadre.